DNS Lookup failure
Okay. I am properly stuck on trying to get radarr.mydomain.com to work on Ubuntu 24.04 with apache2....
Here are my two conference files:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName radarr.vantienhoven.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:7878
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:7878
</Virtualhost>

and then the conf file for my SSL (which works...)
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName radarr.mydomain.com

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx/privkey.pem
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)  ws://localhost:7878/$1 [P,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*) http://localhost:7878/$1 [P,L]
 
 ProxyPass / http://localhost:7878/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:7878/
 
</VirtualHost>

Now... when I access radarr.mydomain.com from within my network, it works perfectly :-)
However, when I try to access it from outside my network, I get the following error:
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request
Reason: DNS lookup failure for: localhost:7878login
I have also update my hosts file to include:
192.168.0.xx radarr.mydomain.com
I have been searching for hours but cannot find a solution!

format your apache entries into command quotes to be more human readable
